# What is the sum $\sum_{j=1}^{2n} j^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the formula to calculate the sum of the following statement?

for example: $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$

The statement I need help with:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2n} j^2$$

Thanks for the help in advance, I am really stuck on this question.

Comment: Just substitute $2n$ in the formula in place of $n$.

Comment: Can you understand properly the notation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n$, or is there a typo?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. What Rohan said is right. It is advised that you show your working on how far you have reached.

Comment: You really mean $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}j^2$? Are you sure you don't mean $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2$ or $\sum_{j=1}^nj^2$?

Comment: how long have you thought about this question?

Answer (score 2):

The formula you mentioned itself contains the answer.

As you know:$\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$.

Here on substituting $2n$ in place of $n$ you will get: $$\sum_{j=1}^{2n} j^2=\frac{1}{6}(2n)(2n+1)(4n+1)=\frac{1}{3}n(2n+1)(4n+1)$$

Comment: Thanks man! Such a simple solution to an answer I have breaking my head on for a while now. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @SamLiemburg

Comment: Thanks @THELONEWOLF. Again, thanks for your great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\\$ $f(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$.
Then what you have to find is $f(2n)$.
And $\\$ $f(2n) = \sum_{j=1}^{2n} j^2 = \frac{1}{6}(2n)((2n)+1)(2(2n)+1)$

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the help!